# Is there a difference between math.inf and cmath.inf in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, complex-numbers, infinity, python-cmath

Is there any difference between the infinities returned by the `math` module and `cmath` module?

Does the complex infinity have an imaginary component of 0?

Answer (score 4):

### Any difference?

No, there is no difference. According to the docs, both `math.inf` and `cmath.inf` are equivalent to `float('inf')`, or floating-point infinity.

If you want a truly complex infinity that has a real component of infinity and an imaginary component of 0, you have to build it yourself: `complex(math.inf, 0)`

There is, however, `cmath.infj`, if you want 0 as a real value and infinity as the imaginary component.

### Constructing imaginary infinity

As others have pointed out `math.inf + 0j` is a bit faster than `complex(math.inf, 0)`. We're talking on the order of nanoseconds though.

Comment: Alternatively, `complex(math.inf, 0)` can be constructed as `math.inf + 0j` or `complex("inf")`. Based on some back of the envelope timing with `timeit`, `math.inf + 0j` is the fastest by a noticable margin (~60 ns, versus 90 ns and 120 ns for `complex("inf")` and `complex(math.inf, 0)`, respectively.)

Comment: @Brian noted in edit

Comment: `complex(math.inf)` is enough; imaginary part is by default zero (and real too, if you use just `complex()`). Anyway, it'd be even better to tweak your program so it handles `float`s, `int`s (or [other types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html)) as well instead of requiring `complex` instances. All of the number types have `imag` part, equal to 0 in case of real numbers.